# IIS7.5 throwing 404.17 error asp.net 4.0 webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I just deployed simple webapplication inside iis7.5 in win 7. No fancy stuff and simple web.config file.  it throwing 404.17 error.

If I place index.html file. it works fine.. looks like asp.net and aspx page not working here.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion will help me.

**Edit:** As **makemoney2010** said,
I did revert to parent, but still not working. see below image which is handler mappings, anything missing here?

[image]

Comment: do you have asp.net registered in your server?

Answer (score 0):

it is simple.it has not permission to execute script or those are not handled in iss configuration.You need to solve it.Click on you site select Mapping hanbdler and then from right pain revert to parent....even check permission on your folder. that's all and it should solve your issue

UPDATE:
This is tipical configuration of my webserver.
If you need assistance to setup your webserver i can help you contact me on skype with id turri.giorgio and i can help you via video conference or team viewer.

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Have you check your permissionh on folder ???? has it IIS_USER has execute permission ???I will update my response Sshortly with pictures